# Select all text in textarea jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make all text in textarea selected when user open it through jquery?

Comment: Not sure if your question is unambigously...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('textarea').on('mouseup', function() { $(this)[0].select(); });​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tu9N7/

Answer (score 1):

[Input.select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Input.select)

```
var eraInput = document.getElementById('era');
eraInput.select();
```

Comment: Wow, great stuff here, jQ didn't do the job, this one did.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('textarea').focus(function() {
  this.select();
})
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/209/)**

#### From the line "when user open it through jquery" I think you need something like:

```
$('textarea').slideDown(function() {
    $(this).focus();
}).focus(function() {
    this.select();
});
```

Here I assume your `textarea` is hidden and you opened it using jQuery event and after open it text will be selected by default.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/210/)**